# How do I modify this LINQ statement to match only if the search term "Label" is at the end of the string?

Tags: c#, string, linq

```
foreach (Label control in Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(c => c.Name.Contains("Label")))
```

That will match if the name contains "Label" but how do I make it only match if the string "Label" is at the end of the string?

Comment: `c.Name.EndsWith("Label")`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find a string that ends with substring, you can use `.EndsWith()` as the method.

```
foreach (Label control in Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(c => c.Name.EndsWith("Label")))
```